# PHP use imagick convert svg to jpg vertical text become transverse

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagick

I want to convert svg to jpg by using php imagick,but the result is not that I'm looking forward to ; this is svg and jpg:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMrdm.jpg)

The code is 
    `$im = new Imagick();
    $svg = file_get_contents($imageFile);
    $im->readImageBlob($svg);
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $im->writeImage($fileUrl.'.jpg');
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();`

The vertical text become transverse, the bold text is more fat than in windows .

My environment is under centOS, the ImageMagick version is 7.8.2 .

Anyone have any idea how to solve this?
Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $svg = path to svg;
        $im = new Imagick();            

        $skinurs= path to watermark.png;
        $watermark = new Imagick();
        $watermark->readImage($skinurs);

        $im->readImageBlob($svg);
        $im->setImageFormat("png32");
        $im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
        $iWidth = $im->getImageWidth();
        $iHeight = $im->getImageHeight();
        $wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
        $wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();

            $watermark->scaleImage($iWidth/3, $iHeight/2);

            $wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
            $wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();
         }
        $im->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER,0,0);
        $im->resizeImage(720, 445, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
        $base64=base64_encode($im);
        $im->clear();
        $im->destroy();
        return 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . $base64;
```

This is a working code to convert svg into png. This might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks， but it is useless , do you have other ideas?